# Copy all output jars with dependencies into one folder

Tags: maven-3

I've got a parent POM.xml defining 4 modules, 3 of which reference the first one ([this project](https://github.com/acadiasoft/simm-lib) to be precise).

I am trying to copy all output jars with their runtime dependencies into one folder using the following commands:

```
mvn package
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:copy-dependencies 
-DoutputDirectory=deps -DincludeScope=runtime
-DexcludeGroupIds=com.acadiasoft.im
```

The first command succeeds and the last fails with the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project simm: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.acadiasoft.im:simm:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.acadiasoft.im:base:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

Note the last parameter `-DexcludeGroupIds=com.acadiasoft.im` which is how I tried working around this error. I also tried excludeArtifactIds to the same effect.

**Question 1:** Why doesn't it work? Why is it not skipping artefacts with group id `com.acadiasoft.im`?

**Question 2:** Is there a way to make maven 'see' the the jars produced in the `mvn package` step and copy them over along with their dependencies?

Version info:

- Maven 3.6.1
- JDK 1.8

Please note that I would prefer a command line based solution rather than having to modify a POM. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working spell is

```
mvn clean install
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=deps -DincludeScope=runtime -DexcludeGroupIds=com.acadiasoft.im
```

note `package` -> `install`

Comment: Thanks a million! I guess maven didn't see the output jars because they were missing from the local repository and `install` installed them there. Thanks a lot!